# Probability that the ticket is numbered $4$

Tags: probability

In a game of tickets,$8$ tickets numbered $1,2,\cdots ,8$ are grouped in the pairs at random and observed pairwise, the lower numbered tickets of pairs are kept and others are thrown and this process is repeated once more.Then the probability that out of the remaining two tickets,one is numbered $4$ is----

The total number of ways in which pairs can be made in first round is
$$\binom82 . \binom62 . \binom42$$

The number of ways for the second round is $\binom42$.for the favourable I understand that $4$ has to pair with either $5,6,7,8$ in first round and one of the remaining  should play with$4$ in the second round which will bring us the desired outcome.however I am not able to go   with this.

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider that $4$ might not "survive" the first round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct question in the first round is not "how many pairings are possible?" it's "for what fraction of pairings does $4$ survive the first round?".  Of the seven possible partners of $4$ in the first round, (all of which are equally likely), $4$ is discarded when paired with $1$, $2$, or $3$ and retained if paired with $5$, $6$, $7$, or $8$.  So in $3/7$ pairings $4$ is discarded and in $4/7$ pairings, $4$ survives.

The second round is a little more complicated.  Assume $4$ enters the second round.  (So we're only considering the four-sevenths of the time that it does so.)  You know $1$ survives and $8$ does not, so the tickets entering the second round are $1$ and $4$ as well as two of $2$, $3$, $5$, $6$, and $7$.  You should analyze how likely each pair of these five are to survive round one (knowing that $1$ and $4$ do).  Then reduce them to the the cases "number of $2$ and $3$ that survive" and "number of $5$, $6$, and $7$ that survive" because these are identical to "number of members of the surviving pair that can out-survive $4$" and "number of members of the surviving pair that cannot".  This gives only three cases moving out of the second round $(0,2)$ (neither member of the pair is smaller than $4$), $(1,1)$ (one member of the pair is smaller and one member larger than $4$), and $(2,0)$ (both members of the pair are smaller than $4$).

In the $(0,2)$ case, $4$ survives unless it is paired with $1$, so $4$ survives to the end two-thirds of the time.

In the $(1,1)$ case, $4$ is finally paired with either $1$ and discarded, the smaller member of the pair and discarded, or the larger member of the pair and survives.  So in only one-third of $(1,1)$ cases does $4$ survive to the end.

In the $(2,0)$ case all other tickets are smaller than $4$, so $4$ is automatically discarded.  There is zero chance that $4$ survives this case.

So work out how likely each pair is, group them into these cases, and multiply $4/7$, the case probability, and the probability $4$ survives that case for each case.  Then add those probabilities to find how probable it is that $4$ survives along some path.  (Note that you can skip the $(2,0)$ case since it will contribute zero.)